# Get Specific Field

Tags: php

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[284]
      public 'option_id' => string '243' (length=3)
      public 'option_name' => string 'upme_profile_fields' (length=19)
      public 'option_value' => string 'a:17:{i:50;a:7:{s:8:"position";s:2:"50";s:4:"type";s:9:"separator";s:4:"meta";s:22:"profile_info_separator";s:4:"name";s:12:"Profile Info";s:7:"private";i:0;s:7:"deleted";i:0;s:17:"show_to_user_role";i:0;}i:60;a:14:{s:8:"position";s:2:"60";s:4:"icon";s:6:"camera";s:5:"field";s:10:"fileupload";s:4:"type";s:8:"usermeta";s:4:"meta";s:8:"user_pic";s:4:"name";s:15:"Profile Picture";s:8:"can_hide";i:0;s:8:"can_edit";i:1;s:7:"private";i:0;s:6:"social";i:0;s:7:"deleted";i:0;s:17:"show_to_user_role";i:0;s:17:"edit_b'... (length=5301)
      public 'autoload' => string 'yes' (length=3)
```

how do i get field 'option_value' from the above output.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your variable name is but you could do something like this:

```
$option_value = $array[0]->option_value;
```

Since its an object inside, use the `->` (arrow operator), and point the desired property.